# Cant import dependency in xcworkplace cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

i am relatively new in ios, especially cocoa pods. i ran into a problem,somehow the IgListKit dependency is un-importable, I already clean build, build 1st then add the import, even deleting the xcworkplace and adding a new one by doing `pod install`

How do I fix it? is it an issue within the Pod? should I file an error? Thank you

How I add the dependencies :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'LearnViper' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.4'
    pod 'RxSwift', '6.2.0'
    pod 'RxCocoa', '6.2.0'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 7.0'
    pod 'SkeletonView'
    pod 'IGListKit', '~> 4.0.0'
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
target 'LearnViper' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.4'
pod 'RxSwift', '6.2.0'
pod 'RxCocoa', '6.2.0'
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 7.0'
pod 'SkeletonView'
pod 'IGListKit', '~> 4.0.0'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to update your gem file with command first

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

then after that open podfile add pods and  install

Comment: already did that also, didnt work at all

Comment: alamo and rx work just fine, but not iglistkit

Comment: anyway, i already installed pod incase you're wondering

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you have to do is add
`use_frameworks!` in your pod file